# Is it possible to make single page application with laravel blade templates and angularjs

Tags: angularjs, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I want make single page application with laravel and angularjs but angular support only html and laravel blade template are php is there any possibility make single page application with laravel blade and angularjs

Comment: With angularjs you may just use Lumen. It's not necessary to use blade. And also, laravel would be an overkill.

Comment: Yes, it is possible!

Comment: @GeorgeKagan can you please tell me.. or suggest me any link...

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible.

Here some links:

- https://github.com/DimitriMikadze/lumen-angular-todo
- http://the-amazing-php.blogspot.com.ng/2015/05/lumen-micro-framework-with-angularjs.html
- https://github.com/bestmomo/lumenangular
- http://anvel.io/

Anvel is of Lumen version 5.3 and Angular 2 with Webpack and there is a good documentation.